# How to http POST complex JSON object to Java Spring backend using Angular 8?

Tags: java, json, spring, httpclient, angular8

I'm using Angular 8 to make HTTP POST request to my Java Spring backend.

POST request in Angular 8 snippet:

```
...
export class TechniqueComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  techniqueInfo: TechniqueInfo = new TechniqueInfo("Gogoplata",{id:1,creatorName:"Kawaishi"},1899,1969);

  postTechnique(){
    this.httpClient.post(`http://localhost:8081/api/TechniqueInfo`, this.techniqueInfo).subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

In my back-end, I am correctly getting the "Gogoplata", "Kawaishi", 1899, and 1969 -- however I am always getting "id" (within that nested object) as 0.

Java (Spring) backend snippet (TechniqueInfo entity class):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="techniqueinfo")
public class TechniqueInfo implements Serializable {
   public TechniqueInfo(){}
   @Id
    @Column(name="techniquename")
    private String techniquename;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="techniqueid")
    private Technique techniqueid;

    @Column(name="birthyear")
    private int birthyear;
    @Column(name="deathyear")
    private int deathyear;
```

Here is the corresponding Technique entity class for the "private Technique techniqueid":

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "techniquelist")
public class Technique implements Serializable {
    public
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="creatorName")
    private String creatorName;
```

In my TechniqueInfo (Angular) class:

```
export class TechniqueInfo{
    constructor(
        public techniquename: string,
        public techniqueid: Object,
        public birthyear: number,
        public deathyear: number
    ){}
}
```

Here is the MVC controller for handling the POST request:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/TechniqueInfo")
@CrossOrigin // allows requests from all domains
public class TechniqueInfoController {
    @Autowired
    private TechniqueInfoService service;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addTechniqueInfo(@RequestBody TechniqueInfo tech){
        service.createTechniqueInfo(tech);
    };
```

I believe the problem may be how I am passing in the POST request object.
`techniqueInfo: TechniqueInfo = new TechniqueInfo("Gogoplata",{id:1,creatorName:"Kawaishi"},1899,1969)`

I am passing in an object ({id:1, creatorName:"Kawaishi"}) within the POST request body incorrectly, which is why Spring is returning me id as 0 instead of 1, even though it is returning creatorName correctly?

I am struggling to know what to pass instead of that object to make id set correctly in the Spring backend.

Comment: You need to show your Spring MVC controller, and note that it is generally unwise to expose your database classes directly through the Web API, because it makes it difficult to modify each as requirements change.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have added the MVC controller